# PHP get Single Value query using

Tags: php, sql

I have to use this code to get single record but in check var_dump get all record please advice me if any one know

```
$selected_result = $mysqli_lib_obj->query("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE id='".$order_id."'");
```

Comment: you can limit your query result with "LIMIT 1" but if your ids are not duplicated you should get only one.

Comment: You also should parameterize that query.

Answer (score 2):

The right Solution would be to limit your result by SQL:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli_lib_obj->prepare("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE id=? LIMIT 1")) {
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $order_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $selected_result = $stmt->get_result();
    $num_of_rows = $selected_result->num_rows;
    while ($row = $selected_result->fetch_assoc()) {
         // Do something with $selected_result
    }
    $stmt->free_result();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

And always use prepared statment, if you don't ... you are letting hacker open doors to your database .

Comment: As you pointed out above, if `id` is a primary key, the `LIMIT` is redundant. I suspect OP has many problems with their data

Comment: Also, never use `bind_result()` with `SELECT *`

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```php
"SELECT * FROM orders WHERE id='".$order_id."' Limit 1"
```

Comment: It's one thing to simply add `LIMIT 1` but without an `ORDER BY` you're not differentiating from any of the other records and leaving the selection to random chance.

Answer (score 0):

The Actual problem lies in the query itself- try this way.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE id='$order_id' limit 1";
```